# Making android app get data from rails table

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and wish to make my Android app work with data created in my rails app.What is the best strategy to auto-generate/auto-update a JSON or an XML feed with the data created by my rails app to be used with my android app?

Answer (score 2):

JSON is the way to go.
Make specific controllers and actions to provide the data that your Android app needs to consume, and use something like the RABL or jbuilder gem to create json templates with the data structure that you want. You will need to use the Json libraries for android

Some further reading for you as it's impossible to provide a more detailed answer to such a general question

http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl

http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder

and a nice simple tutorial on how to post json from Android

http://localtone.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html

and how to consume json

http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/

You should find the time to watch all of that video but it's the last half that is really important.
Then to handle versioning of your Rails API/REST interface or whatever you want to call it
http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning
Rails and Android or iPhone for that matter make an awesome combination.

The above should be enough to get you started at least to get you to the point where you can ask more specific questions, but once you get your head round the basics you really need to use a sync adapter to handle the traffic. The Android development team really URGE you to take the sync adapter approach as can be seen in this very long googl I/O video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Comment: @emcanes Yeah, I like RABL too :) it's definitely my personal preference but jBuilder is also very good and worth a looking at by the OP